# Convert string with prepended 0s to Int in Scala

Tags: string, scala, type-conversion

I'm looking for a simple solution to convert a String in Scala with prepended 0s into an Integer. The values were given 0s when converted to Strings to all have the same length, but I would like a simple solution to convert them back.

Sample data:

```
00001234
00123456
12345678
```

Sample output:

```
1234
123456
12345678
```

I have tried "number".toInt, but I receive a java.lang.NumberFormatException for this.

Any simple solutions?

Comment: Where do you get the exception? `toInt` method works for all your posted scenarios, the way it will fail is when the value can't be represented as an int, in which case you'll need to use the `toLong` method of `BigInt(string)`:
`@ "00001234".toInt ` -> `res2: Int = 1234`, `@ "00123456".toInt` -> `res3: Int = 123456`,`@ "12345678".toInt` -> `res4: Int = 12345678`

Comment: This was the problem. I've been developing Java/Scala code for 8 years and I'm trying to cast a Long as an Int. I must've been staring at my screen too long today, thank you @AlexITC!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
"00001234".dropWhile(_ == '0').toInt
```

Just `"00001234".toInt` seems to work as well.

Comment: That's not required, `toInt` handles `0` prefix properly.